# Custom template for Password Protect Form

Tags: php, wordpress, security

In Wordpress I have created a custom page template using the `page-slug.php` syntax. The page is very different than all the other pages and doesn't need any managed content.

The page needs to be password protected, so I have set the visibility of the page to Password Protected.

What happens:
The password protected box only shows up when include `the_content()` somewhere in the template. The problem is that I can't include the password field on the `page-slug.php` template.

What I want to happen (or something similar):
When you navigate to `http://site/slug/` it takes you to a password page, and then once authenticated it displays the intended page.

Is this possible with default Wordpress functionality? Are there plugins that could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the page doesn't need any content, why not just include the call to "the_content()" and not write any content? If no content has been added, it won't output anything.

Comment: The password form get's included with `the_content()` so it has to be in the template, as far as I know.